# Is there any possibility to filter pandas by list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a df with columns `product_id` and `keyword`. I am iterating over product id by for `group_name, group in s.groupby('product_id')` and in this step, I want to keep groups that contain all elements from the search list.
for example:
[image]

and my search list = `['land', 'cruiser']`

so in the output, I want this:

[image]

I have tried this

```
data[data["keywords"].isin(search_words)]
```

but this method keeps all groups if it contains at least one element from the list, while I groups must contain all elements in the search list.

Comment: Could you include your data as text so that we could with it?

Comment: If you have the data below, do you want group 1 to include 'barn'?  
`df = pd.DataFrame({"product_id": [1,1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   "keywords": ["land", "barn", "land", "land", "cruiser", "barn", "cruiser"]})
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a different answer (in one line!):

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                  'keywords': ["land", "cruiser", "land", "cruiser", "land",
                               "land", "land", "cruiser", "cruiser", "land", "cruiser"]})

search_words = ['land', 'cruiser']

s[[(all(p in x for p in search_words)) \
   for x in s.merge(s.groupby("product_id").apply(
           lambda x: list(set(x["keywords"]))).to_frame(). \
               rename(columns={0: "grouped"}), left_on="product_id",
               right_index=True)["grouped"]]]
#Out: 
#    product_id keywords
#0            1     land
#1            1  cruiser
#2            1     land
#3            1  cruiser
#4            1     land
#9            4     land
#10           4  cruiser
```

### EDIT

I have just used pandas [groupby filtration](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#:%7E:text=x%202%20columns%5D-,Filtration,-%C2%B6), and realised it would be much more simple to use this here instead.  The returned dataframe is exactly the same as the one above, just using a lot less code!

```
s.groupby("product_id").filter(lambda x: all(p in list(set(x["keywords"])) for p in search_words))
```

Answer (score 1):

The core logic here is lifted from [S Rawson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71810410/514608).

Instead of a one-liner, I create some helper variables -- I make a series of product_id and all their associated search terms (product_keywords).  Then I make a series (keepers) of all the product_id that have all the keywords. Finally I use the isin() method to test if dataframe rows have a product_id in that list.

This keeps all terms that are in groups that have all the sought terms; so if group 1 has "land" and "cruiser" and also other words, this gets all of the terms.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"product_id": [1,1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   "keywords": ["land", "barn", "land", "land", "cruiser", "barn", "cruiser"]})

search_list = set(['land', 'cruiser'])

product_keywords = df.groupby("product_id").apply(lambda x: list(set(x["keywords"])))

product_keywords
# product_id
# 1    [barn, cruiser, land]
# 2             [barn, land]
# 3          [cruiser, land]

keepers = product_keywords[product_keywords.apply(lambda found_terms: all(search_term in found_terms for search_term in search_list))]

keepers
# product_id
# 1    [barn, cruiser, land]
# 3          [cruiser, land]


df.loc[df['product_id'].isin(keepers.index)]  
#    product_id keywords
# 0           1     land
# 1           1     barn
# 3           3     land
# 4           1  cruiser
# 6           3  cruiser
```

Comment: It is certainly easier to follow code split up into parts!

Comment: I have just come across pandas filtration, and made a much smaller, more simple line of code for this, in the edit of my answer (in case you haven't come across it yourself).

Comment: S Rawson - No I did not know you could filter at the DataFrameGroupBy object, thank you.  I wonder if it "pushes down" the filter and avoids bringing rows into the groups altogether.   `dir(df.groupby('product_id'))` shows a lot of other attributes to explore, too.

Comment: Oh wow!  That's a useful bit of code, thanks!